# Best way(s) to register a user, including a file upload on mobile

Tags: mobile, users, experience, upload

I'm creating a form for a site which requires, as part of the registration, the user to upload a file (a CV/ resume).

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to handle this, i.e what if they don't have the file on their phone (very likely...)

Comment: Surely the simplest answer is: don't require that they upload a file as part of registration. No?

Comment: I don't really have any control over that, its what the company wants

Comment: Well to be honest if that's the case I would go back to the stakeholders who have commissioned this work and ask what *they* would expect to happen in this (as you say very likely) situation. We'll see what answers people have to your question here anyway, but you should still try to explain to the stakeholders that not everyone (if fact an ever-increasingly fewer people) use the web on their single desktop device with access to all their personal files. Or better yet:- build a prototype where 'File Upload' is a required field and give it to them to test out, see how they manage! ;)

Comment: Not every mobile device can upload files, even if they *are* on the system.  For instance, iOS6 is limited to uploading photos/videos only:  http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I like the sites which enables functionality based on how complete your profile is. You could for example allow access to a limited portion of the functionality of your application before the registration is complete. This way you can layer your registration process from having just the basic information provided (name, email, password), to having all work-related information stored.

CVs are anyway not static information, so even if a user provides a CV at registration, there is a good chance that you'd like an updated version of that CV in a couple of years time.

Answer (score 0):

I think resume upload from mobile should be optional, BUT, user should be alerted prompted/when s/he logs back in via desktop web to upload resume at that time. Agree with other answer that maybe features should be limited while resume is not uploaded, but I don't see any feasible way that a user will easily be able to upload a resume via mobile web. And you don't want to prevent mobile web registrations either. Your best bet is to allow no resume upload via mobile web, and force user to upload resume next desktop web session. I'm never a fan of forcing a user to do anything, but it seems that this is what the client wants.